# using week number to get range of dates with sunday as first day of week in python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

input: `week_number = 34 (or 2022-34)`

expected output:
`["2022-08-21","2022-08-22", "2022-08-23","2022-08-24","2022-08-25","2022-08-26","2022-08-27"]`

First date should be of Sunday
the last date should be Saturday
work with both leap and non leap year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import datetime

week_number = 34
out = []

date = datetime.datetime.strptime(f"2022-{week_number}-0", "%Y-%U-%w")
for day in range(7):
    out.append((date + datetime.timedelta(days=day)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    "2022-08-21",
    "2022-08-22",
    "2022-08-23",
    "2022-08-24",
    "2022-08-25",
    "2022-08-26",
    "2022-08-27",
]
```

---

From the [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes):

> **%U** - Week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week) as
> a zero-padded decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the
> first Sunday are considered to be in week 0.